# Move to trash should delete dependent files cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I developed an application which contain daemon in Mac. It works fine. But when I remove this application from application folder using move to trash, it will not remove the .plist file in the launchAgents folder. So that I can't able to delete this daemon. Please help me on how to remove the dependent files in mac when using Move to Trash

Answer (score 1):

Unless you download some sort of an app uninstaller-- you're going to have to manually delete the .plist as well as the app bundle when you want to completely remove your app.

We have something similar, and what we did is made a bash script that goes through and `rm -rf filenamehere` of all the dependencies we wanted to also be deleted.  Then to make things easier, add an alias to bash profile that will run the script on a `cleanApp` command.